# 400 Bad Request - Dio Flutter - App freezes when api request returns bad request, but works with 200 request

Tags: flutter, authentication, django-rest-framework, error-handling, dio

I have the following code, and the app freezes when incorrect details og typed. When handling the errors the apps also freezes. What am I doing wrong?
I'm using Dio

#api block

```
  Future<dynamic> loginUser(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      developer
          .log('Attempting to login user: $email'); // Log the login attempt
      final response = await _dio.post(
        'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login/',
        options: Options(headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }),
        data: {
          "email": email,
          "password": password,
        },
      ); <---- freezes if response from server is 400

      developer.log('Attempting to login user: $response');
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      // Handle the specific case of a 400 status code
      if (e.response != null && e.response!.statusCode == 400) {
        var errorMessage = "Invalid login details.";
        if (e.response!.data is Map &&
            e.response!.data['non_field_errors'] != null) {
          errorMessage = e.response!.data['non_field_errors'][0];
        }
        return {'error': errorMessage}; // or throw Exception(errorMessage);
      } else {
        // Handle other types of errors

        throw Exception('Network error: ${e.message}');
      }
    }
  }
```

### main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/api/api_service.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as developer; // for logging
import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'GoCardless Onboarding',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const OnboardingScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class OnboardingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const OnboardingScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<OnboardingScreen> createState() => _OnboardingScreenState();
}

class _OnboardingScreenState extends State<OnboardingScreen> {
  final _api = LybApi();
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> loginUsers() async {
    try {
      final res = await _api.loginUser(
        _emailController.text,
        _passwordController.text,
      );

      if (res is Map && res.containsKey('error')) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(res['error']),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade300,
        ));
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: const Text('Login Successful'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade300,
        ));
      }
    } on Exception catch (e, stackTrace) {
      // Log the error and stack trace
      developer.log('Login error: $e', error: e, stackTrace: stackTrace);
      print('Login error: $e'); // Basic logging

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('An error occurred: $e'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade300,
      ));
    }
  }
  //if there is no error, get the user's accesstoken and pass it to HomeScreen

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('GoCardless Onboarding - Step 1'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                controller: _emailController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Email',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                controller: _passwordController,
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Password',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await loginUsers();
              },
              child: const Text('Login'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Response form server
Status code 400 - (wrong credentials)
{
"non_field_errors": [
"Invalid Details."
]
}

Status code 200 - (right credentials, app runs fine)
{
"user": {
"id": 18,
"email": "test@user",
"first_name": "Test User"
},
"token": "1b6277163c18abb299fd41b4a590d2cb18dc3d38ed6385a6f65a809ada05ae18"
}